# How to download .csv file with log in required using python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to log in to download a `.csv` file from this url
https://www.mapmyfitness.com/workout/export/csv. The url redirects the page to this url:
https://www.mapmyfitness.com/auth/login?next=/workout/export/csv

I have tried implemented the below code but come up with this error:

```
username = 'email'
password = 'password'

url1 = 'https://www.mapmyfitness.com/workout/export/csv'
url2 = 'https://www.mapmyfitness.com/auth/login?next=/workout/export/csv'

payload = {'email': username, 'password': password}
requests.post(url2, data=payload)

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(url2, data=payload)
    print(p.text)

    r = s.get(url2)
    # print(r.text)

{"error":"validation/username,password","error_description":"Post body failed validation: {\"username\":\"validation/string\",\"password\":\"validation/string\"}"}
```

I have tried numerous other things but this is the closest I've got to the page not just spitting back the HTML information on the log-in page. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The error is telling you it requires a payload field of `username` and `password`, not email and password.

Comment: @eatmeimadanish tried it, still the same error!

Comment: Oh I see your problem, this doesn't work like that.  The webpage is expecting values input into those fields.  It is not an api route call.

Comment: You should be able to login if you pass your post data to the `json` parameter, and change 'email' to 'username'.

Comment: you need to login with `s.post(url,json={"username":"kcy@outlook.com","password":"dafcasdadad"})`. Note: i do not have an account that i can not figure out if it needs cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you are trying to treat the login page like an API call and those are different animals.  You would need to have python (selenium can do this) actually fill in the actual input fields and parse the result.  This seems cumbersome, and any change to the web page breaks this.

It looks like they have an API for their software, you should actually look at this:

https://developer.underarmour.com/

Clicking a button with Selenium pulled from [How to press login button in selenium python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527991/how-to-press-login-button-in-selenium-python-3)

xpath:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='userid-button'][@type='submit']")
elem.click()
```

css:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.userid-button[type=submit]")
elem.click()
```

Comment: thanks! I will check out getting API access. For now, I got a almost working solution using `selenium`. Do you know how I would be able to click the log in button there? I inspect the button and I'm not sure how to select it to click. I use `find_element_by_id` for `email` and `password`. But it doesn't seem that the button has an `id`

Comment: i wound up using `xpath` instead!

Comment: Ok great!  Glad this got you in the right direction!